# Header And Data Size Are Different

Tags: xml, header, size, corrupt

I have this error message when i tried to upload my apk on the google play:
Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:

Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(23432): Bad XML block: header size 28257 or total size 1936025193 is larger than data size 3069
ERROR: AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt
If you know something, please help me!!

An my manifest.xml is:

```
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.test"
         android:versionCode="1"
         android:versionName="1.0">
         <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="8"
         android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
         <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
         <application
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.StartActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.SafeUseCategoryActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SafeUseActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.ProtractorActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.LoadChartsCategoryActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.ChartsActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.CertmaxPlusActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.AboutActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.NewsActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.ContactActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.LoadWireChartCategory" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.ChangeUserInfoActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        />
    <activity 
        android:name=".activities.SetupActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        />
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.test"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">
     <uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="8"
     android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.StartActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.SafeUseCategoryActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SafeUseActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.ProtractorActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.LoadChartsCategoryActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.ChartsActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.CertmaxPlusActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.AboutActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.NewsActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.ContactActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.LoadWireChartCategory" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.ChangeUserInfoActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    />
<activity 
    android:name=".activities.SetupActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    />
```

Comment: hi what is different? please tell me what the problem is about? thanks